# Sequences for that $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{x_n}$ is divergent and $\sum_{n} \frac{1}{x_n \ln x_n}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

We will denote with $(x_n)$ a given sequence and we introduce the following two series.

$$S^* = \sum_{n} \frac{1}{x_n} \quad \text{and} \quad S_* = \sum_{n} \frac{1}{x_n \ln x_n}.$$

We know that if $(x_n)$ are for example the Fibonacci numbers greater then $1$, then $S^*$ and $S_*$ are convergent. If $(x_n)$ are the prime numbers then $S^*$ is divergent and $S_*$ is [convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029640/sum-p-in-mathcal-p-frac1p-ln-p-converges-or-diverges). If $(x_n)$ are the natural numbers greater then $2$, then both series are divergent.

**Question.** How could we characterise the $(x_n)$ sequences, for that $S^*$ is divergent and $S_*$ is convergent. I would be also glad to see some reference in this topic. If we cannot characterise $(x_n)$ then is there any special property of such sequences?

Comment: A crude requirement for both to be *convergent* is $x_n\approx a^n$ for some $a>0$, which is something Fibonacci numbers enjoy.

If you trust the Erdos Turan conjecture, then $S^*$ diverging implies $x_n$ has arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions. An affirmation of this is the Green-Tao theorem for prime numbers. So perhaps it would be worth studying when $S_*$ diverges/converges if $x_n$ has arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions. This seems difficult...

Comment: @AlexR. Erdős also proved in 1935 that for any sequence where no term divides another $S_*$ is convergent. See details [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1935-04.pdf).

Comment: Ah, you want to characterize all sets which are [large under $\displaystyle\frac1x$ and small under $\displaystyle\frac1{x \log x}$? :-)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898173/generalization-of-small-set-large-set)

Comment: Your question is clear (and +1 btw), I was just making a half-humorous reference to one of my own questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find any characterization that's simpler than your definition itself. The boundary between convergence and divergence is very delicate. For example, if $x_n = n( \log n )(\log\log n) (\log\log\log n)^\alpha$, then $S_*$ converges regardless of the value of $\alpha$, but $S^*$ converges when $\alpha>1$ and diverges when $\alpha\le1$.